# grep/sed + match exactly complex line

Tags: grep

I have the file:

```
  # more file
  (WORD = (TCPIP = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(WORD = ALIAS_NAME)(PORT = 10234))
```

but when I try to match part of the line (by grep -w) in the file , grep also match the line (inspite this is part of the full line)

```
 grep -w "(TCPIP = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(WORD = ALIAS_NAME)(PORT = 10234))" file

 (WORD = (TCPIP = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(WORD = ALIAS_NAME)(PORT = 10234))
```

my question how to match exactly the line in the file

so if I use grep or something else like sed/awk it will be match only the full line?

Lidia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By returning the whole line, grep is simply showing that is has found the string *in that line*. If you only want to *see the matched text on the command line*, you could (for instance) use -o (only matching):

```
echo $name | grep -o "(WORD = (TCPIP = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(WORD = ALIAS_NAME)(PORT = 10234))"
```

Just to see the result on the CL, omit "echo $name | ".

If you want to capture the exact text in your variable, you could do:

```
name=`grep -o "(WORD = (TCPIP = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(WORD = ALIAS_NAME)(PORT = 10234))" /Users/deveritt/Desktop/test.html`
echo $name
(WORD = (TCPIP = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(WORD = ALIAS_NAME)(PORT = 10234))
```

Comment: ...or use the second example with the backticks `